# How to set property on PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnValueMap object?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

Piece of code from test method:

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
  ->method('get')
  ->willReturn($this->returnValueMap(['foo', new FooMock()]));

$service->doSomething($mock);
```

Return value mock:

```
class FooMock {   

  public $bar;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->bar = new \stdClass;   
  }
}
```

Code that I'm testing:

```
class Service {
   function doSomething($object) {
     //do something
     return $object->get('foo')->bar;
   }
}
```

Error:

> Undefined property:
>   PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnValueMap::$bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code here:

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
  ->method('get')
  ->willReturn($this->returnValueMap(['foo', new FooMock()]));
```

You call `returnValueMap` with an argument - array `['foo', new FooMock()]`. However, the method expects an *array of arrays* with mappings ([documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)). Try this:

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
  ->method('get')
  ->willReturn($this->returnValueMap([['foo', new FooMock()]]));
```